# Need to return a max value from multiple columns in a single row in a Google Sheets query

Tags: google-sheets, filter, max, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have Google Sheets data that looks like:

```
12/01/2019   Tom    blah   23    24   25   blah   blah  blah 
12/01/2019   Mary   blah   34    -2   44   blah   blah  blah
12/01/2019   Paul   blah   23     2        blah   blah  blah
11/23/2019   Tom    blah  -23   -33   -2   blah   blah  blah
```

Easy to create a query that gets all the results based on name. But what I need is something that returns all the extra data across the row, but only returns the MAX value of the 3 numbers (or zero if the highest number is negative) - basically something like "Select A, B, C, MAX(D, E, F)". So it would return:

```
12/01/2019   Tom   blah   25  blah  blah  blah
11/23/2019   Tom   blah   0   blah  blah  blah
```

Comment: Do you mean to sort by name, or filter by name?

Comment: You can use filter, sort and if

Comment: filter, sort and if? I can get the rows I need doing a "Select * where B contains 'Tom'" (which will return the two rows). But I want it to return only one column with the max value of the 3 columns (D/E/F) - hope that makes sense.

Comment: I guess I should say - I want it to return all the data in the row, with the exception of these three columns (return only the max value),

Comment: see in my answer

Comment: if all rows of tom will be displayed, so the array_constrain is not needed

Answer (score 1):

Here sample as I said, the data are in range m66:u69, adjust as your data range:

```
=array_constrain(sort(filter( {M66:O69,if(P66:P69>Q66:Q69,if(P66:P69>R66:R69,P66:P69,R66:R69),if(Q66:Q69>R66:R69,Q66:Q69,R66:R69)), S66:U69},N66:N69="Tom"),4,false),1,1000)
```

[image]

Here another formula, where without array_constrain and sort, but will give you result as you need, 2 rows and the max of three columns and if negative to be 0:

```
=filter( {M66:O69,if(P66:P69>Q66:Q69,if(P66:P69>R66:R69,P66:P69*((SIGN(P66:P69)+1)/2),R66:R69*((SIGN(R66:R69)+1)/2)),
         if(Q66:Q69>R66:R69,Q66:Q69*((SIGN(Q66:Q69)+1)/2),R66:R69*((SIGN(R66:R69)+1)/2))), S66:U69},N66:N69="Tom")
```

[image]

Explanation:
1. {"a";"b"...} will give array in rows

2. {"a","b"...} will give array in columns
3. {"a";"b","c","d"} this combine rows and column
4. if(exp1,if(exp2,..,..),if(exp3,..,..)) these are cascade of if to get one data from more data
5. (SIGN(P66:P69)+1)/2 will give 0 to negative and 1 to positive
6. (P66:P69)*((SIGN(P66:P69)+1)/2) will give 0 for negative and as is for positive

Comment: I am a bit confused, why is it not returning two rows - one for 11/23 and one for 12/01? Sorry, I am still relatively new at this...

Comment: I will add explanation about the formula

Comment: Wow, that is nuts. :) Thank you so much for your help! Seems like I need a month to figure out all that it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

to create max of each row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(D2:F<0, 0, D2:F)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A),
 "max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")", )))), 
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

---

and then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({FILTER(A2:C, A2:A<>""), 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(D2:F<0, 0, D2:F)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A),
 "max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")", )))), 
 "select Col2"), FILTER(G2:I, A2:A<>"")}), 
 "where Col2 = 'Tom'", 0))
```

[image: 0]